# TypeScript - Is number bigger or smaller validation responds only when numbers have same 'length'

Tags: javascript, validation, numbers, max, min

Working currently on number validation. I have 2 inputs, and one number cannot be bigger then the other one, and the other one cannot be smaller then the first one.
With arrows in the input field, it works great, but the user can manually enter invalid numbers, and my goal is to revert that number to a valid number.

So for example, from cannot be bigger then to, if I add 'to' 6 and 'from' 8, 'from' number will revert to a valid number which is 6. But if I add another number to 'from', so 'to' is 6 and 'from' is '85', nothing will change, it will register changes but it will not revert it to a valid number.

If numbers have the same 'length', like 60 and 80, 500 and 952, then it will work correctly. But when it's like 5 and 80, or 20 and 965, then the validation will fail.

Here is my HTML and TS

```js
numberFrom: number;
  numberTo: number;

  ngOnNumberChange(event) {
    let to = this.numberTo;
    let from = this.numberFrom;

    if (from < 0) {
      this.numberFrom = from = 0;
    } else if (to < 0) {
      this.numberTo = to = 0;
    }
    if (this.numberFrom > this.numberTo) {
      this.numberFrom = this.numberTo
    }

    if (this.numberTo < this.numberFrom) {
      this.numberTo = this.numberFrom;
    }

  }
```

```html
<input [(ngModel)]="numberFrom" (ngModelChange)="ngOnNumberChange($event)" type="number" [max]="numberTo" [min]="0" [placeholder]="'From'">

<input [min]="numberFrom || 0" [(ngModel)]="numberTo" (ngModelChange)="ngOnNumberChange($event)" type="number" [placeholder]="'To'">
```

Here is it in StackBlitz.
[enter link description here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fmzmhk)

Comment: It's something to do with execution order, and Angular updating the input fields on the screen.  Swap the two `if` statements checking for the sizes around (or lace some debug in them) and you'll see what I mean.  Updating the `from` input triggers the first `if` statement, which causes the second `if` statement to skip (correctly), but the UI isn't updated.  (It looks like the `onChange` event is still in flight or something?)

Comment: You're right. Had to add a small timeout before 'if' checks, so right now it's working properly. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The value of an input is always a string, you need to convert it to a number first before doing your checks.

You can do that by either using `parseInt` or `+`:

```
let to = parseInt(this.numberTo, 10);
let from = parseInt(this.numberFrom, 10);
// OR
let to = +this.numberTo;
let from = +this.numberFrom;
```